# Why can't I enter a PEM Pass Phrase in the prompt?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, openssl, x509

I am trying to install an SSL certificate on my WAMP server.

```
W:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin>echo %OPENSSL_CONF%
w:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\openssl.cnf

W:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin>openssl req -x509 -new -out my.root.ca.crt -
keyout my.root.ca.key -days 3650
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Generating a 1024 bit RSA private key
....++++++
........++++++
writing new private key to 'my.root.ca.key'
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

Enter PEM pass phrase is where I am stuck.  It won't let me type anything.  And also, am I supposed to come up with my own pass phrase and tell this program to use that, or am I supposed to have a pre-determined pass phrase set by... well... apache, openssl, wamp, etc.

Comment: Try typing something and hitting enter?  It's not popping up `*` characters as you type but it should still be getting your input.

Answer (score 4):

The keystrokes are recorded but nothing is echoed back to the screen. Type the passphrase you want and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. You'll be prompted to re-enter the same string to confirm.

Comment: It's a standard design paradigm for terminals. It wasn't until many years after this design was standardized that GUIs started printing asterisks or bullets instead of the password characters.